# How to specify which version of a concrete implementation for an abstract class to autowire in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, abstract-class, autowired

Having the following class structure:

```
public abstract class A {
    String someProperty = "property"

    public abstract void doSomething();
}

@Service
public class Aa extends A {

    @Override
    public abstract void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I did");
    }
}

@Service
public class Ab extends A {

    @Override
    public abstract void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I did something else");
    }
}
```

I need a way to tell Spring which `A` concrete class to `Autowire` in my **Foo** service, based on a property in a *properties* file.

```
@Service
public class Foo {

    @Autowire
    private A assignMeAConcreteClass;
}
```

And in my `properties` file I have this:

```
should-Aa-be-used: {true, false}
```

Comment: Just use a [profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `@Service` annotation, instead write a [`@Bean`-annotated method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java) in a configuration class that reads the properties, and returns the appropriate `A` instance.

Comment: It may work but it also means that only one of the two implementations would be added in the container. Actually the OP want to autowire a specific implementation in a specific bean. He/she doesn't tell that only one of two would be in the container.

Comment: You have a point, although it's not clear if that's what the OP wants or not. @Brad please clarify

Comment: having the property in the file as a boolean, I currently have only two implementations based in that flag

Comment: @JB Nizet It is right. Anyway your way is interesting and may be helpful in this specific case.

Comment: @JBNizet just tested your solution and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Not a new way but in your case I think that a possible suitable way would be to use
`FactoryBean` in the class that wants to inject the bean conditionally.
The idea is simple : you implement `FactoryBean` by parameterizing it with the interface of the bean that you want to inject and override `getObject()` to inject the wished implementation :

```
public class FactoryBeanA  implements FactoryBean<A> {   

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Value("${should-Aa-be-used}")
    private boolean shouldBeUsed;

    @Override
    public A getObject() {

        if (shouldBeUsed) {
            return applicationContext.getBean(Aa.class));

        return applicationContext.getBean(Ab.class));

    }
}
```

But FactoryBean instances are not classic beans.  You have to configure it specifically.

You could configure it in a Spring Java configuration in this way :

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryBeanAConfiguration{

    @Bean(name = "factoryBeanA")
    public FactoryBeanA factoryBeanA() {
         return new FactoryBeanA();
    }

    @Bean
    public beanA() throws Exception {
        return factoryBeanA().getObject();
    }
}
```